# Definition for set of ratios of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Just as there is a difference between polynomials in a variable $x$ and polynomial functions in the variable $x$, I am looking for the terminology for the ratio of two polynomials. They "look" like rational functions, but there is no regard to domains and ranges.

For example,
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \frac{6x + 9}{3x - 12}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
g(x) = \frac{2x + 3}{x - 4}
\end{equation*}
are the same Mobius transformation, but they have different coefficients and constant terms.

Is there an algebraic term for the ratio of polynomials in the variable $x$, and is there an algebraic term for the ring of all such ratios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field of all quotients of polynomials in the variable $X$ over a field $K$ is most often denoted by 
$$K(X)= \{\frac{f}{g} | f,g\in K[X], g \neq 0\}$$
and is called the *function field*. The elements are called *rational fraction* or also *rational function*. Still, the quotients are really just regarded as fractions of polynomials and not as functions. 
It is the field of fractions of the integral domain $K[X]$, that is the smallest field that contains all polynomials.

Comment: You have reminded me of this phrase. $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ over the field of real numbers."

Comment: In this field, are the quotients $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that I have in my post distinct elements?

Comment: @Adelyn No, they are not. As in $\mathbb{Q}$, in the construction of $K(X)$ one identifies fractions if they have the same reduced presentation, that is $\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f'}{g'}$ if and only if $fg'=f'g$.